# When I try to import pandas in Jupyter notebook, it throws a type error, how do I solve it? I reinstalledboth but nothing seems to work

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

When I try to import pandas it gives this error:
[Snippet of error][1]

This happens only in jupyter notebook
When I try to import it through VS code it works fine.
I am using python 3.8 btw.

I uninstalled Jupyter notebook and Pandas as well and then again installed them but that doesnt seem to work.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last) Input In [1], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 import pandas as pd File c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py:22, in <module>
     19 del hard_dependencies, dependency, missing_dependencies
     21 # numpy compat
---> 22 from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev
     24 try:
     25     from pandas._libs import hashtable as _hashtable, lib as _lib, tslib as _tslib File c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\__init__.py:20, in <module>
     14 from pandas._typing import F
     15 from pandas.compat.numpy import (
     16     is_numpy_dev,
     17     np_version_under1p19,
     18     np_version_under1p20,
     19 )
---> 20 from pandas.compat.pyarrow import (
     21     pa_version_under1p01,
     22     pa_version_under2p0,
     23     pa_version_under3p0,
     24     pa_version_under4p0,
     25 )
     27 PY39 = sys.version_info >= (3, 9)
     28 PY310 = sys.version_info >= (3, 10) File c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\compat\pyarrow.py:6, in <module>
      3 from pandas.util.version import Version
      5 try:
----> 6     import pyarrow as pa
      8     _pa_version = pa.__version__
      9     _palv = Version(_pa_version) File c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\__init__.py:65, in <module>
     63 _gc_enabled = _gc.isenabled()
     64 _gc.disable()
---> 65 import pyarrow.lib as _lib
     66 if _gc_enabled:
     67     _gc.enable() File c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\compat.pxi:43, in init pyarrow.lib() File c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\__init__.py:3, in <module>
      1 from __future__ import absolute_import
----> 3 from cloudpickle.cloudpickle import *
      5 __version__ = '0.6.1' File c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py:167, in <module>
    147     else:
    148         return types.CodeType(
    149             co.co_argcount,
    150             co.co_kwonlyargcount,    (...)
    163             (),
    164         )
--> 167 _cell_set_template_code = _make_cell_set_template_code()
    170 def cell_set(cell, value):
    171     """Set the value of a closure cell.
    172     """ File c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\cloudpickle\cloudpickle.py:148, in _make_cell_set_template_code()
    131     return types.CodeType(
    132         co.co_argcount,
    133         co.co_nlocals,    (...)
    145         (),
    146     )
    147 else:
--> 148     return types.CodeType(
    149         co.co_argcount,
    150         co.co_kwonlyargcount,
    151         co.co_nlocals,
    152         co.co_stacksize,
    153         co.co_flags,
    154         co.co_code,
    155         co.co_consts,
    156         co.co_names,
    157         co.co_varnames,
    158         co.co_filename,
    159         co.co_name,
    160         co.co_firstlineno,
    161         co.co_lnotab,
    162         co.co_cellvars,  # this is the trickery
    163         (),
    164     ) TypeError: an integer is required (got type bytes)
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question and post the full error traceback in text format, not as an image (see [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285551).

Comment: Stack Oveflow is not letting me to  post the entire error traceback

Comment: Copy-paste the **text** into the post

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have updated the code for better understanding